# MySQL Query Extremely Slow any Suggestions?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this MySQL query which seems to be very very slow. It takes 3 seconds to run. This is trying to get all the posts from either who they're following or any interests they have. Also its trying to make sure it doesn'tshow any duplicate shares that match any post_id. What do you guys think I should do?

```
SELECT p.*,
       IFNULL(post_data_share, UUID()) AS unq_share,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_time) AS a
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users_interests i ON (i.user_id=1
                                AND p.post_interest = i.interest)
LEFT JOIN following f ON (f.user_id=1
                          AND p.post_user_id = f.follower_id)
WHERE (post_user_id=1
       OR f.follower_id IS NOT NULL
       OR i.interest IS NOT NULL)
  AND (POST_DATA_SHARE NOT IN
         (SELECT POST_ID
          FROM posts p
          LEFT JOIN following f ON f.user_id=1
          AND p.post_user_id = f.follower_id
          LEFT JOIN users_interests i ON (i.user_id=1
                                          AND p.post_interest = i.interest)
          WHERE (post_user_id=1
                 OR f.follower_id IS NOT NULL
                 OR i.interest IS NOT NULL))
       OR POST_DATA_SHARE IS NULL)
GROUP BY unq_share
ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: is innodb or myisam ?

Comment: MyISAM. I tried InnoDB (added indexes, optimized my.cnf, etc) and it went up to 3.5 second run time. My server has 90gb ram left, the cpu's are barely used, and I have raid-10 6x intel 330 180gb ssd's

Comment: did you try explain command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Below are the Performance tips will definitely make difference.

- Try Explain Statement.
- Alter the Table by Normalize your tables by adding Primary Key and Foreign Key
- Add Index for Repeated Values.
- Avoid select * from table. Mention the specify column name.
- Convert IS NULL to (='')
- Convert IS NOT NULL to (!='')
- Avoid More OR Condition.
- MySQL Configurations to explore

  - key_buffer_size
  - innodb_buffer_pool_size
  - query_cache_size
  - thread_cache

Much more refer this SO Answer [Best my.cnf configuration for a 8GB MySQL server with MyISAM use only](https://serverfault.com/questions/354872/best-my-cnf-configuration-for-a-8gb-mysql-server-with-myisam-use-only)

Comment: Thanks, just the index value along cut 2 seconds of it, the * select cut off another 0.3, then the convert IS NOT NULL !="" cut 0.1 second, and I removed the whole NOT IN statement and decided to do a IF(p.post_data_share !="", p.post_data_bump, p.post_id) AS test then group it by test which saved me another 0.4. Now the query runs under 200ms which is good enough for me. Would you think I'll be able to bring this down if I do an InnoDB swap?

Comment: dont require. this is best enough i believe

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the execution plan for the query. Here is a link to MySQL documentation on the EXPLAIN keyword to show you how the optimizer is structuring your query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

If CPU usage is low, likely the bottleneck is disk access for large table scans.

The way the query is executed is often different from how it was written. Once you see how the execution plan is structured, you are probably going to create indexes on the largest joins. Every table should have one clustered index (often it is created by default), but other fields can often benefit from unclustered indexes.

If the problem is extremely bad and this is vital to your application, you may want to consider reorganizing the database.